# How can get the array of stripe customer card api PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I wanted to know how can I get the data of the stripe api array in PHP. This is my code:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');


$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
    'KEY'
  );
  $stripe->customers->retrieveSource(
    'CUSTOMER_ID',
    'CARD_ID',
  );
 print_r($stripe);
```

I tried to use print_r to get the result on screen but is not showing me that data, just showing me api details of stripe. How can I get the card detail from customer in STRIPE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every API requests you make with Stripe's API will return an object. You have to store the response in a variable if you want to access it.

If we take your example you want this

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_test_123');
$card = $stripe->customers->retrieveSource('cus_123','card_ABC');
```

With that the `$card` variable is now an instance of the `Card` [class](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/Card.php) in the library with all the properties you care about.

Now, this is old code that is mostly deprecated. In 2018, Stripe released a new API called the PaymentMethods API which unifies all payment method types together from card to ACH/SEPA/BACS Debit to many others like iDEAL and Konbini. The legacy objects like `card_123` work with that API too.

I would strongly recommend using the new API instead so call either the Retrieve PaymentMethod [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/retrieve) to retrieve a specific one like this:

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_test_123');
$pm = $stripe->paymentMethods->retrieve('pm_123');
```

Or you can call the List PaymentMethods [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/customer_list) instead with the `type` parameter to find all the cards attaches to that customer. This returns a list of PaymentMethods and you can paginate through it as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination):

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_test_123');
$paymentMethods = $stripe->customers->allPaymentMethods(
  'cus_9utnxg47pWjV1e',
  [
    'type' => 'card',
  ]
);
foreach ($paymentMethods->autoPagingIterator() as $paymentMethod) {
  // Do something with $paymentMethod
}
```

Comment: Maan thank you so much for that answer it's working now really apreciate you made my day